# c++ Need clear examples showing difference between decltype(x) & decltype((x))

Tags: c++, c++11

I have read many times on the difference between decltype(x) and decltype((x)). One example is as per below.

> x is the name of a variable, so decltype(x) is int. But wrapping the name x in parentheses—“(x)”—yields an expression more complicated than a name. Being a name, x is an lvalue, and C++ defines the expression (x) to be an lvalue, too. decltype((x)) is therefore int&. Putting parentheses around a name can change the type that decltype reports for it!

Can someone show me the output of a variable say x where the output type of decltype(x) and decltype((xx)) are different? I need an example explicitly showing difference in output.

Appreciate that.
Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

If you declare a variable with type `decltype((x))`, it is a reference. The easiest way to see the difference is probably this:

```
int x = 0;
decltype(x) copy = x;      // creates an int which is a copy of x
decltype((x)) ref = x;     // creates a reference to x

ref = 7;                   // changes x
copy = 99;                 // does not change x

std::cout << x << '\n';    // prints 7
std::cout << copy << '\n'; // prints 99
std::cout << ref << '\n';  // prints 7
```

As for when you would use `decltype((x))`, I hesitate to say never, but I can say that I've never had a reason to do it in my own code.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say we have `int a = 0`, then `decltype(a)` would be `int`, since `a` directly names the entity. `decltype((a))`, on the other hand, should be `int&`, since `(a)` is an expression that does not refer directly to the entity.

The same holds for members as well, for example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

struct S {
  int v = 0;  
};

int main() {
  S s;
  std::cout << std::is_same<decltype(s.v), int>() << std::endl;
  std::cout << std::is_same<decltype((s.v)), int&>() << std::endl;
}
```

`decltype(s.v)` is `int`, since `s.v` directly refers to the name of an entity. `decltype((s.v))`, on the other hand, is `int&`. `(s.v)` does not refer directly to the name of the entity.

Comment: In what situation would one use decltype((s.v)) which is int&. (s.v)? what's the benefit of it?

Comment: When you want to declare a reference to the type of some variable `a`. An equivalent would be `decltype(a)&`.